# Altering the splitcontainer panels on C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, open-source

for my project, im assigned to change the interface of an open source software. I'm aware that a splitcontainer has a built in panels (panel1 and panel2). Panel1 has a smaller width (lets say 60) and Panel 2 has a larger width (lets say 120). How do i alter those panels making Panel1 wider than Panel2. I'm pretty new at this, the help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post the code you have so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please look at [ask].

Answer (score 0):

To adjust the splitcontainer width and height, you need to `select the whole splitcontainer control first` then put your mouse pointer on the division of panel1 and panel2 to see that you can now adjust it, just like on this picture:

[image]

I am trying to screenshot it on my computer but the mouse is not included on my screenshot. Make sure you select the whole control, and not the panel1 or panel2 since you cannot adjust it by selecting panel1 or panel2.